# How to calculate what resistors are needed for a specific voltage output, when using a variable regulator

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, resistance

I am using the LM1117, I need to generate 2 voltage rails, 1.32V, 3.75,  but have no idea what level of resistance is required to generate them, is there a equation to work this out?

Comment: What did the datasheet (that you didn't link to) say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because very obviously no own research effort has been done. Page one for crying out loud.

Answer (score 5):

Parts have this awesome thing called datasheet and it gives you information about using your part. For LM1117, the equation is given on [page 1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf):

[image]